# watchOS 2: haptic feedback in background

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos-2

I think I know the answer to this question already, but I wanted to ask just to be thorough.

Consider the Apple Watch built-in Maps app. When you're using turn-by-turn directions, when it's time to turn left or right, the watch plays a custom haptic pattern - even though the screen is off and the app is backgrounded. Another example is while you're doing a workout - if you've set a goal, you'll get a light tap on your wrist when you get 50% there and 100% there, even if you're not looking at the watch at the time (screen off, app backgrounded).

In watchOS 2, is there any way for us 3rd party developers to have an app play a certain haptic pattern when the screen is off and the app is backgrounded? I know the `playHaptic:` method works while the app is active to let you play several different kinds of haptic patterns, and I know that while the app is inactive, you can have a notification come in - but the notification would only ever play the 'notification' haptic feeling, no choice in that.

Comment: Has this been addressed by Apple yet? My app @ChronicTimer would greatly benefit from this. I have a workout session but still can't provide this functionality.

Comment: No, and I doubt anything will change until MAYBE WWDC 2016 next year. Apple's not in the habit of offering new APIs except when the latest major OS version is still in beta (between June and September usually).

Answer (score 2):

You can only run custom code when you app is active. So I´m afraid you can't do this.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks. That HealthKit stuff is interesting, though, I didn't know that... we're thinking about an internal company app (no App Store), so we could probably pretend to be a workout app and discard the heart rate data. Do you know how often the heart rate data comes in? Are there any other frameworks where you can get periodic callbacks and a chance to run code?

Comment: You will get HeartRate samples approx. every 3-5 seconds. No other frameworks as I´m aware of atm..

Comment: Are you looking at HKWorkoutSessionDelegate workoutSession:didChangeToState:fromState:? The documentation says "If your application is suspended, the delegate receives this call after the application resumes. This means you may receive the notification long after the state changed. Check the date parameter to determine when the state change actually occurred." https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKWorkoutSessionDelegate_ProtocolReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/HKWorkoutSessionDelegate/workoutSession:didChangeToState:fromState:date:

Comment: HealthKit query streams delay delivering their results while the watch screen is off. You will get all of your results at the same time when the app wakes back up, so this method will not work even for workout apps. Apple may have designed it this way because playing a haptic momentarily stops the heart rate sensor from gathering data. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceDevice_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceDevice/playHaptic:

Comment: I am in a similar situation where I want the Apple Watch app to wake up when an event is triggered on the paired iPhone.  My app deactivates too quickly and I can't push the new data coming from the iPhone  to the watch. Sounds like this is currently not possible except in Apple apps or apps which claim to do something else like be a health or map app. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i'm playing haptic in background,
first of all you need to enable background mod in Capabilities for WatchExtensionand to enable:Workout Processing and Audio,Airplay.
Also you need to enable for WatchExtension HealthKit.

#import < HealthKit/HealthKit.h >
add HKWorkoutSessionDelegate

```
-(void)awakeWithContext:(id)context{

[super awakeWithContext:context];
HKHealthStore *cwHealthStore = [[HKHealthStore alloc] init];
cwConfiguration = [[HKWorkoutConfiguration alloc] init];
cwConfiguration.activityType = HKWorkoutActivityTypeOther;
NSError *error;
HKWorkoutSession *cwSession = [[HKWorkoutSession alloc] initWithConfiguration:cwConfiguration error:&error];
[cwSession setDelegate:self];
if (!error) {
    [cwHealthStore startWorkoutSession:cwSession];
}
    [self test];
 }


#pragma mark WorkoutSession Delegates

- (void)workoutSession:(HKWorkoutSession *)workoutSession
  didChangeToState:(HKWorkoutSessionState)toState
         fromState:(HKWorkoutSessionState)fromState
              date:(NSDate *)date{
NSLog(@"------>%ld", (long)toState);
}

 - (void)workoutSession:(HKWorkoutSession *)workoutSession didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

And now you can play haptic in background.

```
  -(void)test{
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerTrick:) userInfo:nil repeats:true];


 }

- (void)timerTrick:(NSTimer *)time {

        [[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] playHaptic:WKHapticTypeStart];

}
```

Don't forghet to stop workout Session after leaving controller:

```
     [cwHealthStore endWorkoutSession:cwSession];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to post an update to my own question a couple years later - in watchOS 3 workout apps were granted background execution, but no haptics (I think).

In watchOS 4, workout apps, audio recording apps and navigation apps have background execution; navigation apps can send haptics in the background. Furthermore, the "frontmost app" (app last used which still appears if wrist is raised within 2 minutes, or 8 if extended frontmost time is enabled) has some privileges for sending haptics at the conclusion of a WatchConnectivity or NSURLSession data transfer, or when a notification comes in. See the docs for details.